# Parsing String to Double

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Existing String to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063115/existing-string-to-double)

I'm trying to parse String into Double, and I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do it. If anyone can help me check on it, and give feedback I'd really appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
    String amount = enterAmount.getText().toString();
    double subtotal = Double.valueOf(amount).doubleValue();
```

Thank you in advance for your kind comments.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When an answer helped you out of your problem, you should accept it by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Comment: you can use 2 methods to parse double. 
1. double subtotal = Double.valueOf(amount);
2. double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(amount);

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(amount);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String amount = enterAmount.getText();
double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(amount);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap this call around a `try-catch` block and handle `NumberFormatException` which will be thrown if the string cannot be parsed as `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do, is (when using a `JFormattedTextField` or a `JTextField`) replacing all the comma's by points and removing the spaces:

```
String amount = enterAmount.getText();
amount = amount.replace(",",".").replace(" ", "");
double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(amount);
```

This means following input will work:

```
12
1,2
1.2
200 000
200 000,01
```

The commas are used in a lot of European countries: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDecimalSeparator.svg)

> Blue = point;
>   Green = comma;
>   Red = Momayyez (/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use some logic to determine if it is a valid number. Here is a function for testing integers:

```
public static int validateInteger(String number)
{
  int i = -1;

  try {
  i = Integer.parseInt(number);
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
  {}
  catch (NullPointerException npe)
  {}

  return i;
}
```

In your case, you have to change the Integer.parseInt() function into whatever type you want.

Comment: What if `-1` is entered and this is valid?

Comment: The function is not static in the sense that you can't change it. If you want to allow the number -1 then that is of course perfectly fine. Choose another return value, any number, with a very low probability of being a correctly entered number. I used this function to test if a port number was valid and since negative numbers can't be used as port numbers, the number -1 was a good indication of this.

Comment: you are right that any invalid value could be used.  You could return a long, or you could just throw the NumberFormatException an have the caller catch it rather than check the value.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Many situation requires unique solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be **international**, you should probably use this:

```
DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale).parse(numberAsString).doubleValue()
```